# How to remove a href tag with jQuery but keep the text natural?

Tags: html, jquery

This is my markup:

```
<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Comment author 1</a></div>
```

This is what I want:

```
<div class="comment">Comment author 1</div>
```

Is there a way to do this with jQuery? If so please help me, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is use `text(function)` so you isolate specific instances.

This will loop over all elements with that class and overwrite any elements inside each one with just the text

```js
$('.comment').text((_, txt) => txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Comment author 1</a></div>
<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Another  author </a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var txt = $('.comment a').text();
  $('.comment').html(txt);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Comment author 1</a></div>
```

### Updated to loop through all .comment divs

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.comment').each(function(){
     var txt = $(this).find('a').text();
     $(this).html(txt);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Comment author 1</a></div>
<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Comment author 2</a></div>
<div class="comment"><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Comment author 3</a></div>
```

Comment: In fact, it does work. You can confirm that it works by using DevTools *(In* **Run Code Snippet:** *Right-Click on the text and choose Inspect Element)* Do you need for it to loop over all `.comment` divs and change them all? If so, you can use a `$.each()` loop (answer updated) -- or, you can use charlietfl's much fancier answer to do the same thing. Use the one you like.